# Reset notification timer by hitting button (swift3)

Tags: ios, if-statement, timer, swift3, notifications

My code has two buttons:

- One should start a "notification sequence" where a notification will appear every 30 seconds indefinitely.
- The other should stop the notification sequence.

If you hit the start button while the notification sequence is in progress, the timer should reset -- so the next notification should appear 30s after the last time you hit the button. If you hit the button every 25s, you should never see a notification.

I have only included the code that is needed to solve this problem:

```
 func startTimer(){

    let timeInterval = 30.0
    if isGrantedAccess && !timer.isValid { //allowed notification and timer off
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.sendNotification()
        })}}
func stopTimer(){
    //shut down timer
    timer.invalidate()
    //clear out any pending and delivered notifications
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
}
    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    startTimer()
}
@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    stopTimer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is commonly referred to as debouncing, with a twist. Commonly used on type as you go searches, etc.

I would use a repeating timer and simply cancel it if the button is tapped before the 30 seconds is up, and start the thirty second repeating timer again every time it fires. I would also fire the local notifications immediately and invalidate the timers instead of invalidating the local notifications.

Here's a gist with an example in objective-c that you could refactor for use in swift. 
[Objective-C Debounce Example](https://gist.github.com/stevenojo/e1dcc2b3e2fd4ed1f411eef88e254cb0)

Comment: Could you do it in swift3? I am not very good at converting obj c.